# How to modify css for every <p> under a specific datafield selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to add text after each numerical weight value.
Here's what the html looks like:

```
<table class="shop_attributes">
    <div class="field" data-field-id="product_size">
        <strong class="field__label field__label--above">product_size</strong>
        
        <div class="field__content">
            <p>66 x 81 x 61</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="field" data-field-id="product_weight">
        <strong class="field__label field__label--above">product_weight</strong>
        <div class="field__content">
            <p>128</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</table>
```

The results I want to display is:
**product_size**
66 x 81 x 61 in

**product_weight**
128 lbs

From what I know, we can select the data field using

```
div[data-field-id=product_size]
div[data-field-id=product_weight]
```

And we can use > p to select just the p elements under the data fields.
This is what I've done

```
    div[data-field-id="product_weight"] > p{
    white-space: nowrap;
    content: " lbs";
    }
```

However this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `div[data-field-id="product_weight"] > p{` will work if the p is a direct child, not the case here , remove the **>** selector or make it `div[data-field-id="product_weight"] > div > p{` to go to your nested p

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear I have read your problem carefully, after that I have solved your problem which I have attached as below code.

```
div[data-field-id="product_size"] > div > p::after {
    content: " in";
}

div[data-field-id="product_weight"] > div > p::after {
    content: " lbs";
}
```

I hope my solution will solve your problem.
Note:- If you want to add content after and before any element then you need to use CSS Pseudo-elements (like ::after and ::before)